# Solving non-linear first order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics, differential

I'm try to solve this differential equation:

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{Ay^{1/2}} {By^{1/2}-Bx^{1/2}-C} - \frac{Ax^{1/2}} {(By^{1/2}-Bx^{1/2}-C)} 
$$

I tried to solve it but seems to have reached a roadblock here.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What is the application, and what type of solution are you looking for?

Comment: What is the roadblock?  Please show your work to date.